# Xamarin Forms On Platform The property 'Default' is set more than once

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms version 3.2.0.809874-pre3.

I am facing a problem that with this version I am getting the error "The property 'Default' is set more than once" when using OnPlatform at XAML.

Here is my code:

```
<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
        <On Platform="Android">10,5,10,0</On>
        <On Platform="iOS">10,20,10,0</On>
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Padding>
```

Comment: I tested you code but can't reproduce this issue on my side, could you please post more detailed codes? or maybe share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem through online repo

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2608

Answer (score 2):

I'm was getting this too...
Looks like this is just an intellisence bug.
The apps compile fine.

You can build the solution F6 and the error goes away...but resurfaces when you edit the file.